# Upload de imagem com Axios para um servidor Node.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, file-upload, axios

Estou tentando fazer um upload de imagem usando a biblioteca *Axios*, mas ela não está chegando no back-end.

**Input da imagem**

```
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="file" name="file">
```

Obs: Meu formulário já está com o `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

**Código JQuery**

```
var formData = new FormData();
var imagefile = document.querySelector('#file');
formData.append("image", imagefile.files[0]);
axios.post('http://localhost:3030/api/admin/employees', {
  cpf,
  formData
}, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
})
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

**Node.js retornando os dados**

```
return res.send(req.body);
```

**Retorno da API**

```
config: {
  url: "http://localhost:3030/api/admin/employees",
  method: "post",
  data: "{"cpf":"321.321.321-32","formData":{}}",
  headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), …
}
data: {}
headers: {content-length: "2", content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8"}
request: XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
```

Já tentei de muitas formas mas nada está funcionando.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No Node.js vamos usar um middleware para tratar de arquivos para o tipo `multipart/form-data`. Eu utilizo o [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer).

Para o app.js:

```js
const multer = require("multer");
...
...
let upload = multer();

// Esta é a rota a ser usada pelo 'axios': http://localhost:3000/image-upload.
// O campo 'fileimage' será a chave que o multer irá 
// procurar pelo arquivo de imagem.
app.post("/image-upload", upload.single('fileimage'), (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.file);
res.status(200).json({ message: "success!" });
});
```

Agora no seu .js no front-end, vamos ajustar o objeto `formData` e não iremos passar o campo `cpf` "solto" junto com o objeto `formData`, mas sim iremos inserir o `cpf` dentro do `formData`:

```js
const formData = new FormData();
const imagefile = document.querySelector("#file");

// 'fileimage' é o campo que o 'multer' procura o arquivo de imagem.
formData.append("fileimage", imagefile.files[0]);
formData.append("cpf", '1234567890'); // cpf junto ao formData.

axios.post("http://localhost:3000/image-upload", formData, {
  headers: {
  "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data; boundary=${formData._boundary}`,
  }
}).then(response => console.log(response));
```

O parametro `boundary` serve como recurso para separar `chaves` de `valores` quando um formulário for submetido. Algo semelhante ao tipo `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` onde o servidor sabe que as chaves são separadas por `&`, como exemplo:

```
nome=cardeal&cpf=12345678900
```

Para o tipo `multipart/form-data`, o `boundary` tem função similar ao `&`.

### Atenção

> Para entidades do tipo multipart, [*a diretiva boundary é obrigatória.*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type)

---

Feita a requisição, no `console.log` no terminal do Node.js é esperado o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]