# Problemas com formData em upload múltiplo Express e Multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, react

Estou com problemas para realizar upload de multiplas imagens para o backend. O método no backend está correto, quando testo via insominia da certo, porem do meu front não gera os dados corretamente.

Assim que clico nas imagens para fazer upload executo a seguinte função:

```
let data = new FormData();
    
for (const file of files) {
  data.append("images", file);
}

data.append("clientId", "2");

const response = await requestAPI({
  params: `/image/upload`,
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    'Content-Type' : undefined,
  },
  body: data,
});
```

E no meu backend espero da seguinte maneira :

Rota :

```
this.router.post(
  '/upload',
  upload.array('images', 20),
  (req: Request, res: Response) => this.imageController.imageUpload(req, res)
)
```

Tanto o `req.files` quanto `req.body` retornam `undefined` (vazio) no controller.

**Nota: Se eu não passo o cabeçalho como `undefined` nada acontece, passando assim gera o seguinte erro:**

```
images is not iterable
```

Comment: Olá Victor, tenho umas dúvidas, primeiro, você não chegou a testar com `"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"` no cabeçalho?

Comment: Testei sim, ele gera o seguinte erro com esse cabeçalho "Error: Multipart: Boundary not found"

Comment: [Veja se ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/420362/upload-de-imagem-com-axios-para-um-servidor-node-js/420615#420615). Você tentou declarar a diretiva `boundary` desta forma: `"Content-Type":  "multipart/form-data; boundary=${tamanho_aqui}"`.

Comment: Tentei realizar igual passado no link que você enviou e também ja tinha tentado outras maneiras com boundary porem nada com sucesso. Com ele o retorno vira " files = [] body : [Object null prototype] {}"

Comment: Um detalhe que esqueci de mencionar....isso aqui `data.append("images", file);` sobreescreve o campo `images` com o ultimo `file`? Não seria melhor fazer um push para um array `arr.push(file)` e depois inserir no campo `images` (`data.append("images", arr);`)? Estou tentando ajudar, mas fica um pouco dificil sem testar por que estou sem tempo, mas se eu consegui fazer uns testes, posso tentar ajudar ainda mais.

Comment: Saquei, assim que der aqui vou fazer testes com o push e atualizo aqui! Obrigado!